# Facebook SDK Feed Picture wrong size

Tags: javascript, sdk, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a facebook button share, and it works with Javascript SDK. In my Feed Dialog i have an image (picture parameter), it works fine, but the picture renders small. What do i need to Facebook render a larger size?

My code at the moment is:

```
FB.ui({
        method: 'feed',
        link: 'http://www.website.com',
        picture: 'http://img.imagensfree.com/2012/08/imagem-bonita-para-facebook.jpg',
        display: 'popup'
}
```

Help :'(